# Featured Questions per time

Tags: discussion, bounty, statistics

I observed that there are many more featured questions at math.SE than on some other SE-pages. I wonder whether this increases per time, and how it increases. Is the increase linear with active users (one would expect that) or different?

So especially I am wondering whether there is a graph with: x-axis: time from start of math.SE, y-axis: number of featured questions.

It would be interesting, and I see the information of time and bounties is still in the system (one can see it in the user pages).

Thanks for info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will find any insight here, but anyway:

#### New bounties per month

[image: bounties]

#### New users per month

[image: users]

#### Cumulative count of bounties

[image: cum-bounties]

#### Cumulative count of users

[image: cum-users]

Sources: [bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/219830/bounties-and-questions-by-month), [users](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/230871/new-users-per-month)

Comment: Cool thank you! It's interesting, haven't seen these subsites. Secondly I'm a bit surprised, because I expected the number of bounties grows faster than the users. But its not (at least approximativly).